# "unassigned local variable 'mylist' error" given loop containing initiatization will be entered once? And how to make the code recursive?

Tags: c#

```
List<string> Getlist()
{
    List<string> mylist;
    for (bool successFlag = false; !successFlag; )  //It will definitely enter the loop once.
    {
        successFlag = true;
        mylist = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            var CDF = GetCDF(); // IEnumerable, each call of GetCDF() gives different result
            if (!CDF.Any())
            {
                fail++;
                successFlag = false;
                break;
            }
            string item = GetNext(CDF);
            mylist.Add(item);
        }
    }
    return mylist; // Here IDE poses an error
}
```

I guess there is a way to recursively use `Getlist()` instead of do a `for` loop and `flag` retry, maybe some kind of immutable method?

i dont wanna initiate the list outside the loop because i would like to discard the list when `successFlag` is `false`;

Discard simply means when `successFlag = false`, then `mylist.removeall`. And then start everything over again as fresh, so I am asking for an approach to recursively call `GetList()` instead of clear the states in the method

**Update**

`do while` works!

Comment: I don't see any variable `a` in your code.

Comment: Your code looks strange. Why call GetCDF in a loop? Will every call return the same enumerable or a different? What does GetNext do? Why do you overwrite `mylist` in each iteration of the loop? You lose the result of the previous iterations like this.

Comment: Could you show the exact error message you are getting? Also, what exactly is this piece of code trying to do? This info will help you get a good answer.

Comment: I find it unusual that you use a "for" loop for boolean checking. Why not instead initialize successFlag before and use while(!successFlag) ?

Comment: @RolandK : By using `while` i have to declare the Flag before the loop, while in `For` i can do that in the condition expression. Looks better IMO

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth : question adds more explanation as u requested.

Comment: @colinfang: "Looks better IMO": Nope, it doesn't. It looks **very** strange :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has to do with this line. If it doesn't run you List would never be initialized.

```
for (bool successFlag = true; !successFlag; )
```

Now if you change your code to this it should work fine.

```
    List<string> Getlist()
    {
        List<string> mylist= new List<string>();
        for (bool successFlag = true; !successFlag; )
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                var CDF = GetCDF(); // IEnumerable
                if (!CDF.Any())
                {
                    fail++;
                    successFlag = false;
                    break;
                }
                string item = GetNext(CDF);
                mylist.Add(item);
            }
        }
        return mylist;
    }
```

Update :

Run untill GetCDF(); is not empty. This can cause an infinite loop if GetCDF() is always empty!!!

```
List<string> Getlist()
{
    List<string> mylist= new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        var CDF = GetCDF(); // IEnumerable
        if (!CDF.Any())
        {
                        Thread.Sleep(1000); //Sleep for 1 second.   
            fail++;
            return Getlist();
        }
        string item = GetNext(CDF);
        mylist.Add(item);
    }

    return mylist;
}
```

Comment: i dont wanna initiate the list outside the loop because i would like to discard the list when `successFlag` is `false`;

Comment: @colinfang, when you mean discard the list, what do you mean? do you want to null, or the items that are in the list untill the sucessFlag is false.

Comment: simply just like when `successFlag = false`, then `mylist.removeall`. And then start everything over again as fresh, so I am asking for an approach to recursively call GetList() instead of clear the states in the method.

Comment: Looks nice, i will try it, thx. but why sleep?  I can guarantee there will be a valid solution somehow beyond code concept.

Comment: @colinfang, I'm assuming that the GetCDF() method reads data from somewhere, now if GetCDF return nothing, imagine doing this a few times a second, you cpu usage is going to shoot up. So I put in the sleep to give the GetCDF a chance to "rest". If this solution is correct please mark it as accepted. :)

Comment: could I somehow integrate `if (!CDF.Any())
        { 
            fail++;
            return Getlist();
        }` into `GetNext()` method?

Comment: @colinfang let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2770/discussion-between-jethro-and-colinfang)

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign a value to `mylist` outside of the loop. That's what's causing the error in question. The compiler sees that you are returning `mylist` potentially without ever assigning to it. It doesn't analyze your outer loop to determine that it will always return at least once.

```
List<string> Getlist()
{
    List<string> mylist = new List<string>();
    for (bool successFlag = true; !successFlag; )
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            var CDF = GetCDF(); // IEnumerable
            if (!CDF.Any())
            {
                fail++;
                successFlag = false;
                break;
            }
            string item = GetNext(CDF);
            mylist.Add(item);
        }
    }
    return mylist;
}
```

However, there might be other problems. For instance, `n` is not declared anywhere that we can see from this code example.

Comment: i dont wanna initiate the list outside the loop because i would like to discard the list when `successFlag` is `false`;

Comment: You must initialize it to something outside the loop. Set it to `null` if you don't want to `new` it.

Comment: Or `new` it and call `Clear` every iteration. This whole thing does seem a little odd though. Maybe if you elaborate more about what you're actually doing, it might help elicit better advice.

Answer (score 2):

First you declare `mylist`, then you instantiate it inside a loop that could potentially execute zero times (as far as the compiler's static analysis is concerned), then you return it. That causes the error.

Simple solutions:

- If you want to preserve existing behaviour exactly, then declare and instantiate the list up front, e.g. `List<string> mylist = null;`
- If you want to change the behaviour slightly and return a zero-length list instead of null, then move `mylist = new List<string>();` outside the loop.

Comment: the first approach is fine, the second one would keep undesired items in the list. (as previous items stored in failed run remain)

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: I see you "corrected" the code in question, so the following is not valid anymore...

Your loop basically reads:

```
        for (bool successFlag = true; false;  ) {
            //do something
        }
```

The inner instructions will never be executed even once

Comment: Wow. I totally didn't see that. Nice find. (I think the author of the original post has changed this part meanwhile)

Comment: yes, i changed that, but error remains... maybe i should use do while?

Answer (score 1):

Because you have

```
List<string> mylist;
```

and not

```
List<string> mylist = null;
```

Comment: or even `var mylist = new List<string>();`

Answer (score 1):

A for loop is evaluated only in case the condition evaluates to true, so if its false then in such scenario it is unassigned.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are initializing mylist in the for loop but returning it outside of the for loop. The way you are doing it currently will empty your list on every iteration of the outside loop as well.